# Strange inconsistency bug when setting top and left style properties via js

Tags: javascript, html, css, mousemove

I create a div element with fixed position and size. Then I set it's `top` and `left` style properties via js in the `mousemove` event handler.

```
const mouse = document.getElementById('mouse');
window.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  mouse.style.left = e.offsetX + 'px';
  mouse.style.top = e.offsetY + 'px';
  console.log(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xqa91b23/4/ (wiggle your mouse around to see the bug)

It appears that about half of the assignments work, the rest of the time the css properties end up being set to 0px. I am logging the mouse position as passed into the `mousemove` event handler, and it does not correspond to the values which end up being assigned to the element's `style` attribute. The strangest part of this is that if I add `transform: translate(-50px, -50px)` to the element then the incorrect assignments incorporate this offset, ending up as 50px. This occurs in both chrome and firefox.

Some of the things I have tried:

- Setting style via `element.style.setProperty`, with and without `important`
- Changing element positioning to `absolute` and `relative`
- Positioning body and html elements as `fixed`, `absolute` and `relative` with 100% width and height
- Flooring mousemove's `event.offset`'s (despite them showing as whole numbers in the console)

This one has me banging my head against the wall. I have dynamically set offset properties in the past with no problem. My suspicion is that it has something to do with the number to string conversion applied by `+ 'px'`, but that doesn't explain the strange behavior when adding a translation.

Comment: `#mouse { pointer-events: none; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of the use of [`offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) and [`offsetY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetY) properties of the event. These parameters are relative to event target, not the window i.e. when `mousemove` event triggers `offsetX` and `offsetY` are calculated based on `#mouse`. To fix this you need to use ***[`e.clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX)*** and ***[`e.clientY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientY)***.

```js
const mouse = document.getElementById('mouse');
window.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  mouse.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
  mouse.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
  console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
});
```

```css
#mouse {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mouse"></div>
```

Comment: My goodness, now I feel really stupid! That's what I get for trying to write code while sleep deprived